# Analyzing an ARM generated gdb corefile from local PC

Tags: c, debugging, centos, arm

I spent a lot of time on finding a complete solution on remote debugging and analyzing corefiles. Didn't succeed finding a relevant post on stackoverflow also.

Remote debugging could be done quite easily but analyzing a corefile generated in my arm linux (CentOS kernel) gives me "Could not load shared library symbols for" errors. So it gives me only a very few backtraces due to unloaded arm library symbols

I tried linking to arm versions of libraries but there are so many.

Please help me to find a solution to analyze the ARM corefiles without much manual work.

**Following is my system setup**

```
 - My PC is running CentOS and ARM target is also running CentOS kernel
 - Use Linaro as the cross compiler to generate the ARM application
 - Use arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb to debug
```

**I follow the below steps to analyze the corefile**

```
 - Generate the corefile in the target
 - SCP corefile to my local CentOS machine
 - Run gdb analysis using the below command
```

> $> /opt/linaro/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb [ARM applicataion path]
>   [Corefile path]

**My result is something like this**

```
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 16 libraries, e.g. linux-vdso.so.1.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
Core was generated by `./cioffi'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xb6ab248c in ?? ()
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 24662)]
(gdb) by
Undefined command: "by".  Try "help".
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb6ab248c in ?? ()
#1  0x00397994 in network::satellite::modem::Afterburner::init (this=0x0) at /home/sajith/cioffi/cioffi-linux/components/network/satellite/network_satellite_modem_afterburner.cc:125
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x3a666c5a
(gdb)
```

`bt full` also gives only few details of that thread.

I'm ok with any solutions which help me to see the full stacktrace either on the target or PC.

Comment: It is just as the error message say, "Could not load shared...".  You need to transfer the '.so' list from the target as well as the core.  Then you can use "set sysroot" or just ["set solib-search-path"](http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/set_solib-search-path) is probably better.

Comment: I tried sysroot. All the arm libraries needed are loaded but not linux-vdso.so.1. It's giving "warning: Corrupted shared library list: 0x0 != 0x14c7f8". Internet says it's injected by the kernel to every process but I can't find it anywhere on my target either. Do you know how to find/link to it? If that's done can be satisfied with that for the time being.

Comment: Can you upgrade to 7.12 of gdb?  You can also extract it as per [this blog](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/) using `dd` and appropriate offsets.  I think it may  also be in your Linux source (under arch/arm/vdso).

Comment: Vdso issue is resolved. Thanks! 
Upgraded to gdb 7.12. still the same. I'm seeing "Shared library is missing debugging information" and "warning: Corrupted shared library list: 0x0 != 0x14c7f8", "Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)" errors.